# settype of arrayadapter android

Tags: android, spinner, typeface

Here is my code how to set my spinner and I want to set a custom font on its items My class is extends Activity and my partial code is like this

```
  Spinner supportSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.supportSpinner);
  ArrayAdapter supportAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,supports);

  supportSpinner.setAdapter(supportAdapter);
```

btw supports is a string arraylist of my items for my spinner
I want to do such a thing but it doesnt allow

```
     Typeface type = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "comic.ttf");
     supportSpinner.setTypeface(type);
```

how can I change my spinners textviews typeface?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using

```
 android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item
```

Create your own layout, you then will use your current code

```
 Typeface type = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "comic.ttf");
 supportSpinner.setTypeface(type);
```

but set it on the textview in your custom layout for each spinner item

Answer (score 1):

instead of using `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item` create your own layout, and inside XML layout editor there's the option for the TypeFace you want. No need to do any code.

Comment: should I add an extra xml file ? Isnt there any other way too much for just a spinner there should be an easier way isnt it ?

Comment: creating XML layouts is part of Android programming. But you could also override the `getView()` of the adapter call `View v= super.getView(...)` and then find the text view with `v.findViewById(android.R.id... // check autocomplete, something like text1` and change the typeface with the code you have.

Answer (score 1):

for array adapters::

```
Typeface typeNormal = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "roboto_lite.ttf");



timearray = new ArrayAdapter<String>(DetailsActivity.this,R.layout.floorrow,R.id.txt, flor){


                         public View getView(int pos, View convertView, android.view.ViewGroup parent) {


                                View v = convertView;
                                if(v== null){
                                    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                                    v=vi.inflate(R.layout.floorrow, null);
                                }
                                TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txt);
                                tv.setText(flor.get(pos));
                                tv.setTypeface(typeNormal);

                                return v;


                         };




                     };


                    lv_building.setAdapter(timearray);
```